# Can a foreigner enter Spain unvaccinated?

Tags: covid-19, spain

Is it possible to enter Spain by plane unvaccinated? I see [here](https://travelsafe.spain.info/en/requirements-before-arriving-in-spain-from-third-countries/#:%7E:text=1.,vaccination%20course%20against%20COVID%2D19) that:

> 1. If you travel to Spain by air (except children under 12 years of age and travellers in international transit), you must present one of the following certificates:
>
> - a) Vaccination certificate: confirming that you have received a valid vaccination course against COVID-19.
> - b) Diagnostic test certificate: to confirm that you have had a negative diagnostic test.
> - c) Recovery certificate: confirming that, after a positive diagnostic test result, you have recovered from a SARS-CoV-2 infection.

Can someone confirm if these rules are still in place?

Comment: You mean from outside the Schengen area? I entered Spain twice from another Schengen country in recent months, by train and by plane and didn't notice any check whatsoever (I am fully vaccinated and didn't particularly care whether it was required or not).

Comment: why would you do that, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Official](https://www.spth.gob.es/) [websites](https://www.sanidad.gob.es/en/profesionales/saludPublica/ccayes/alertasActual/nCov/spth.htm) suggest this is no longer current or at least no longer enforced in the same way. It is still recommended not to travel with Covid-19 symptoms.

Anecdotally, I entered Spain twice in recent months, by train and by plane, and did not have to prove I was vaccinated. However, I was coming from another Schengen country in both cases.

Comment: The COVID rules does not apply to travelers coming by AIR from EU/Schengen countries: https://www.sanidad.gob.es/en/profesionales/saludPublica/sanidadExterior/CHS/Pdf/FAQs_EN_V16.pdf

Comment: @Bartors Thanks, I suspected that might be the case.

Answer (score 2):

**Can a foreigner enter Spain unvaccinated?**

**Yes**

Although I have yet to find an official Spanish announcement, the UK Government's website for [Foreign Travel Advice, Spain](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/spain/entry-requirements#entry-rules-in-response-to-coronavirus-covid-19)
says that:

> From 21 October 2022, all COVID-19 travel restrictions for travellers to Spain have been lifted.

And a [euronews.com](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.euronews.com/travel/amp/2022/10/21/spain-travel-restrictions-covid-tests-vaxx-rules-and-masks-explained-in-full) article dated 21/10/2022 at 10:10 says:

> Spain has lifted all its remaining COVID restrictions. Until today, it was the only European country that still had restrictions in place for non-EU travellers.

Comment: Cross-posted on [LawSE](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/85585/35069)